# LVL error - cant reference LVL in my project

Tags: android

I am following the android licensing documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) and when i get to the step that I add the reference of the licensing project (in eclipse) to my project, I get an error in the console (see below) and my project doesnt build. Any ideas on how i can around this? I tried a couple searches on google, but I didnt come up with anything. Thanks.

Error seen:

```
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp] ERROR: Unknown option '--auto-add-overlay'
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp] 
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp] Usage:
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp] 
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2010-09-26 05:54:41 - MyApp]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP: Did you manage to solve your problem?

I'm also getting this into problem while trying to use th LVL. I get this error in addition:

"Target 'Android 2.1' does not support building project with libraries."

Thanks.

Solved:
An SDK update was necessary. "Android 2.1" revision 1 was installed and revision 2 is necessary in order to use Library projects.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryReqts